# Unable to Retrieve data-score Values from Website

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape from second rating-score values from the following URL: https://www.kununu.com/de/pan-dacom-networking4/bewertung/40726463-005e-45d9-af11-37e7afbd5110

The HTML structure of the page includes some rating-score attributes that I need to extract. However, I'm having trouble retrieving these values using Python and libraries like BeautifulSoup.

Here's a snippet of the HTML structure:

````
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = 'https://www.kununu.com/de/pan-dacom-networking4/bewertung/40726463-005e-45d9-af11-37e7afbd5110'

response = get(url)
soup = bs(response.text, 'html.parser')
span_element = soup.find('span', class_='index__stars__nfK6S index__medium__CyRQn index__stars__bpFJl') ('data-score')[0:3]

print(span_element)```

However, when I run this code, I get a KeyError: 'data-score'.

Can someone please guide me on how to retrieve the data-score values from this website correctly? Is there a different approach or library I should be using?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
````

Answer (score 2):

To select element that has `data-score=` attribute you can do (in general, use as few CSS classes as possible because today the pages are mostly dynamic and CSS classes change often):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.kununu.com/de/pan-dacom-networking4/bewertung/40726463-005e-45d9-af11-37e7afbd5110"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
score = soup.select_one("[data-score]")
print(score["data-score"])
```

Prints:

```
3
```

---

EDIT:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.kununu.com/de/pan-dacom-networking4/bewertung/40726463-005e-45d9-af11-37e7afbd5110"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

for div in soup.select("div:has(>h4):has(> p)"):
    name = div.h4.text
    text = div.p.text
    print(name)
    print(text)
    print("-" * 80)
```

Prints:

```
Verbesserungsvorschläge
Verschlanken, klare Strukturen und klare Richtung schaffen und sich nicht weiter im IT Ocean umhertreiben lassen
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Arbeitsatmosphäre
Diese hat leider sehr gelitten durch die Übernahme und es gibt eine klare Disbalance und fast eine Arroganz zwischen den beiden Pan Dacoms
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Kommunikation
Seit der Zusammenführung gibt es noch weniger Entscheidungen und es fehlt eine klare Führung und der Mut Entscheidungen zu fällen und umzusetzen.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Vorgesetztenverhalten
Versprechen werden nicht eingehalten
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Interessante Aufgaben
Interessant geht so aber vorallem fehlt die Innovation bei der PDN
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

EDIT 2:

The score numbers are embedded within the `<script>` element. To decode them you can use:

```py
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.kununu.com/de/pan-dacom-networking4/bewertung/40726463-005e-45d9-af11-37e7afbd5110"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
data = json.loads(soup.select_one("#__NEXT_DATA__").text)

print(data["props"]["initialReduxState"]["singleReview"]["ratings"])
```

Prints:

```
[
    {
        "id": "atmosphere",
        "score": 2,
        "roundedScore": 2,
        "text": "Diese hat leider sehr gelitten durch die Übernahme und es gibt eine klare Disbalance und fast eine Arroganz zwischen den beiden Pan Dacoms",
    },
    {
        "id": "communication",
        "score": 2,
        "roundedScore": 2,
        "text": "Seit der Zusammenführung gibt es noch weniger Entscheidungen und es fehlt eine klare Führung und der Mut Entscheidungen zu fällen und umzusetzen.",
    },
    {
        "id": "leadership",
        "score": 2,
        "roundedScore": 2,
        "text": "Versprechen werden nicht eingehalten",
    },
    {
        "id": "tasks",
        "score": 2,
        "roundedScore": 2,
        "text": "Interessant geht so aber vorallem fehlt die Innovation bei der PDN",
    },
    {"id": "teamwork", "score": 4, "roundedScore": 4, "text": None},
    {"id": "workLife", "score": 5, "roundedScore": 5, "text": None},
    {"id": "equality", "score": 3, "roundedScore": 3, "text": None},
    {"id": "oldColleagues", "score": 4, "roundedScore": 4, "text": None},
    {"id": "workConditions", "score": 4, "roundedScore": 4, "text": None},
    {"id": "environment", "score": 3, "roundedScore": 3, "text": None},
    {"id": "salary", "score": 3, "roundedScore": 3, "text": None},
    {"id": "image", "score": 3, "roundedScore": 3, "text": None},
    {"id": "career", "score": 2, "roundedScore": 2, "text": None},
]
```

Comment: sorry I want to form a second rating score.

Comment: @MasudAlNahid Which second rating? The 3,7?

Comment: please check this image https://imgur.com/gallery/7SCPjR7

Comment: Sorry brother it's without rating values. please check this  code ```<span class="index__stars__nfK6S index__medium__CyRQn index__stars__bpFJl" data-fillcolor="butterscotch" data-score="2"></span>```

I need the (data-score="2" ) values.

Comment: @MasudAlNahid See my edit 2.

Comment: hello, @andrej-kesely this code has a little problem, json.load() has changed language or auto translate changed language. How i can solve this pretty problem?

Comment: @MasudAlNahid Probably it's the cookie (`"kununu_country": "de"`). When you open Web Developer Tools -> Network Tab and refresh the page you should see the cookies there.